# Segment to exclude based on a page view and an event

Tags: google-analytics

We have a website that provides information about our SAAS product, it also has a login button that redirects our users to the saas app that is on another domain.

I want to create a segment that excludes these users from our analytics, they all take the same journey of hitting the home page then clicking login which fires the event.

How can I achieve this, I can see how to filter for an event and path but not exclude if both these happen

Answer (score 1):

On the Analytics page:

```
Configure -> Audiences -> Create custom audience
```

Here you may choose on which conditions the users will be included in this audience. The idea is to include all users except those who clicked on the login button. So as a condition you can specify click event and make sure that it was not on the login button, and how to achieve that depends on your metrics.